# Is there a PC controller that behaves exactly like an Xbox 360/PC Windows Controller?

Tags: pc, controllers

I have an Xbox 360 Wireless Controller for Windows and I know that it's very good and one of the most or even the only, sometimes, PC controller supported by recent games.

A friend of mine would like to know if there is an alternative product, possibly cheaper, that **behaves exactly like the Microsoft one**, so that even the games cannot understand the difference.

Comment: It's very annoying when the new pc game You bought works with the xbox controller exclusively =S - I'm looking forward to the answers!

Comment: Sometimes you can hack the config files to use any old controller.  I did it for bioshock.

Comment: A small note: i wouldn't recommend doing this, due to the fact that the reason these controllers are cheaper is usually because they use inferior parts, and will likely break in some way quickly.

Comment: @RCIX cheap not always mean low quality, and viceversa

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about Shopping Recommendations, which we do not support as per the [FAQ].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, do you specifically not want a Microsoft controller?

Other companies make an xbox 360 compatible controller. They use the same drivers, so it works well for the PC

- [Razer Onza](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004DTLZMQ)
- [Logitech Chillstream](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IX1NDC)
- [PDP Afterglow](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fs%3Fie%3DUTF8%26x%3D0%26ref_%3Dnb%5Fsb%5Fnoss%26fsc%3D-1%26ih%3D3%5F6%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F1.55%5F63%26y%3D0%26field-keywords%3Dafterglow%26url%3Dnode%253D14112981&tag=mckayswebsite-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=390957)
- MadCatz: [Modern Warfare 2 - Black](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MZZLMS), [Modern Warfare 2 - Snow](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002NNKTB2), [White / Black](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002W7ZNGU), [Various NFL Teams](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fs%3Fie%3DUTF8%26x%3D0%26ref_%3Dnb%5Fsb%5Fnoss%26fsc%3D-1%26ih%3D2%5F2%5F1%5F0%5F0%5F1%5F1%5F0%5F0%5F1.15%5F77%26y%3D0%26field-keywords%3DNFL%26url%3Dnode%253D14112981&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=390957), [Street Fighter IV Fightpads](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fs%3Fie%3DUTF8%26x%3D0%26ref_%3Dnb%5Fsb%5Fnoss%26fsc%3D-1%26ih%3D6%5F1%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F0%5F2.72%5F79%26y%3D0%26field-keywords%3DFightpad%26url%3Dnode%253D14112981&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=390957)
- [Hori Controllers](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fs%3Fie%3DUTF8%26redirect%3Dtrue%26ref_%3Dsr%5Fnr%5Fp%5F4%5F6%26bbn%3D14112981%26qid%3D1279815008%26rnid%3D345753011%26rh%3Dn%253A468642%252Cn%253A%252111846801%252Cn%253A14220161%252Cn%253A14112941%252Cn%253A14112981%252Cp%5F4%253AHori&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=390957)

But if you do want Microsoft-brand controls that work for the PC, there are wired

- [Wired Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BT4CF4)
- [Wired Xbox](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B6MLTQ)

and wireless

- [Wireless Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KA5T6A)

solutions for the PC.

Any of those should behave identically to the XBox controller.

If you can manage to get your hands on a

- [Wireless Gaming Receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2)

Any wireless Xbox 360 compatible controllers (even those made by third parties) should work fine and behave identically to the original controller.

Comment: I just found the Chillstream at a ridiculous price (14.90 euro) on a shop. My friend bought one and another me too! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 23):

I take it that your friend is aware that there is also a wired version of the PC 360 controller, which is much cheaper than the wireless version?

http://www.amazon.co.uk/-/dp/B000BK4C80?tag=invihand-21

EDIT: For those in the U.S. that want a link:
[http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Controller/dp/B000B6MLTQ/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1279527631&sr=8-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B6MLTQ)

Answer (score 7):

http://www.jayceooi.com/2009/01/19/download-xbox-360-controller-emulator-for-pc-games/

This is an emulator that allows any controller to function as and appear as a 360 controller. I've had success with it, but make sure it works for you before you go out and buy 4 usb controllers.

Comment: Nice! This could be useful to reuse my old PS2 controllers.

Comment: This worked really good with Bastion and my "MDC" generic controller, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend picking up the MadCatz Xbox360 wired controller. All the xbox wired controllers are Windows compatible, and the MadCatz controller is at least a good 15 bucks cheaper than the Microsoft version. I use a Madcatz for pc gaming all the time, and it works pretty well.

Prices: http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=madcatz+wired+xbox+360+controller&hl=en&cid=3875636771555494077&ei=K3lATI3lLqiEjQSM8P3TCA&sa=title&ved=0CAcQ8wIwADgA#p

Lowest listed is only 17 bucks new.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Microsoft used to make a wireless usb dongle for xbox 360 wireless controllers.  I tried to find one recently bud had no luck.

But the wired controllers have always been plug and play, for me.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's only about playing PC games that require an xbox controller, you can use *any* gamepad together with [x360ce](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/), which emulates one.

Comment: shameless plug to a related question by me: [How to use my gamepad globally as xbox controller (on PC)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45906/how-to-use-my-gamepad-globally-as-xbox-controller-on-pc)

Answer (score 1):

If your friend has a PS3, he can use a PS3 controller as an XBox controller using [Motionjoy](http://www.motioninjoy.com/).