# How to use my gamepad globally as xbox controller (on PC)?

Tags: pc, controllers

I figure using [x360ce](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) I can use my gamepad in some games which claim to require a xbox controller. However, this requires me putting two files (`xinput1_3.dll` and `x360ce.ini`) into the respective game's folder<sup>1</sup>.

Is there any way to have this gamepad-as-xbox-controller behaviour active globally without needing to copy this file into each respective game's folder?

<sub>1)</sub><sub>According to [the x360ce manual](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/wiki/MainPage), for some games renaming the dll to `xinput1_1.dll`, `xinput1_2.dll` or `XInput9_1_0.dll` is required</sub>

Comment: I'd imagine you'd be able to stick it in `C:\Windows\System32` replacing the one that exists there.  Be sure to back up the old one first.  That's where "global" stuff usually goes including applications and drivers.  Though do that at your own risk.

Comment: @JeffMercado I tried that and additionally overwriting xinput1_1.dll and xinput1_2.dll as well as the [manual](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/wiki/MainPage) mentions, but XInput9_1_0.dll cannot be overwritten (even as admin). The other three files are not sufficient it seems (it is owned by "Trusted Installer" instead of Administrator, and I can't seem to modify ownership or permissions. Maybe there is a good reason for this though...)

Comment: If you _really_ want to do this, do it in safe mode.  Those are the DirectX drivers and it seems `XInput9_1_0.dll` is actually in use by the system.  Going in safe mode should avoid that.

Comment: @JeffMercado safe mode was not needed, I could take ownership as admin. But even after restarting the PC this still did not work out, so I restored the backups. I wonder though why the dll only seems to work when put in the game directory but not system32... (It's Solar2 on Steam btw, I don't think I have other xbox-only games)

Comment: There's a good chance that the files in the system directory are being restored by Windows as they are not the "original" files.  It actually does that for a lot of other system files.

Comment: @JeffMercado no, the file was still the x360ce dll, I checked that after restart. But still, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @JeffMercado could you post this as answer anyway? I'd upvote it and maybe someone else has an idea why it doesn't work (or maybe I made a mistake somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I made it work was putting the actual software and files in every one of my PC games directories that can use a 360 controller.

Comment: precisely, and I was wondering if there was a way to avoid this and having this applied to all games installed in the future...

Comment: not that i could find, perhaps if you still put it in every game directory then add a command to the shortcut of the game to launch that file first?

Comment: oh, one doesn't have to start another program, putting the dll's (plus the .ini created by `x360ce.exe`) into the respective game executable's folder once is already enough. It's just that locating the .exe and putting the .dll there for every game that needs it (i.e. first figuring out whether it doesn't support the gamepad without x360ce) is a bit annoying. But until someone shows another option that works globally I'll accept your answer :-7

Answer (score 3):

**See EDIT**

You must be using a 64-bit system. Your problem is that you're not replacing the right DLLs.

On 64-bit Windows, `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` is used for 32-bit DLLs and `C:\Windows\System32` is used for 64-bit ones.

Download the [latest x360ce 64-bit dll](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/downloads/detail?name=xinput_r444_x64.zip&can=1&q=), rename to `xinput1_1.dll`, `xinput1_2.dll`, `xinput1_3.dll` and `xinput9_1_0.dll` and put all of these in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Put the 32-bit ones already generated by x360ce in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.
This should work.

**EDIT**: It won't. Games crash. After some source code research, I found that the x360ce dlls **require** the original dlls to be present in the system directories. The only way I can think of is asking the developer to add a feature to specify a directory for the original DLLs or edit the source code on your own. Other than that it's impossible. I'll try to do that myself and if he doesn't approve, I'll try to provide my own build here.

Comment: Any luck with getting it implemented/making a custom build?

Comment: I'm sorry. Got caught up with things. The custom build is still very possible however.

Comment: Cool man, please drop me a line if it happens.

Comment: @kotekzot I requested this as a feature, it shouldn't be to difficult if someone finds the time to implement it: https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/issues/detail?id=604

Comment: @kotekzot Huh, it's been [declined](https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/issues/detail?id=604#c1) rather harshly... Though a simple string search replacing `xinput1_3.dll` should allow one to create a global version...

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get this to work fairly well by moving ***xinput.dll*** and ***x360ce.ini*** to my syswow64 folder.

So far, my games are able to detect an Xbox 360 controller, even though I am using a generic gamepad.

This should be especially useful for Killer Instinct, as Killer Instinct is an 'app', and does not give you access to the game folder.

I tested this on a Sony Vaio laptop, with a generic gamepad, and configured with x360ce.

I tested the controller on Tales of Zestiria successfully. This did not work, however, on Final Fantasy XIII. I also tested Dragon Ball ZenoVerse; however, the **a** button would not register for jump. It still registered correctly for menu input.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having a normal Analog USB Gamepad and want to use it as your XBOX 360 Controller then here is a detailed step by step tutorial that will guide you through the whole procedure how you can emulate your normal gamepad to work as XBOX 360 Controller...It worked for me and I hope it works for you also..Thanks

http://www.rushinformation.com/use-normal-gamepad-xbox-360-controller/

Comment: sorry, but link-only answers are useless - what if the link goes stale? you should at least summarise its contents. In this case that's pointless though, since that site merely states how to use x360ce, which I already knew to start with...

Answer (score -2):

I was always looking forward to that for I have lots of local multiplayer games which need controllers and I only have one Xbox controller so am always busy copying files into game folders.

But, If One controller is all you need then you might want to use Pinnacle game profiler. For multiple controllers yet may be possible but not for every game, [what developer says](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/forum/showthread.php?29554-multiple-controllers-for-a-game-that-natively-supports-360-controllers), or maybe in future there'll be an update to it. seems they are working on it. Or you could ask them your need.

Comment: While http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/features looks actually interesting, I'm afraid this doesn't not answer my question since it seems to require an even more elaborate setup. But thanks for your input nonetheless